# Python parsedatetime: get current month / first of the month

Tags: python

I'm using the parsedatetime library in my Python script and it appears that "last month" works and "next month" but not "this month."

What am I missing? Is there a way to get the first day of the current month?

Edit:
Sorry, here's some code:

```
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt
p = pdt.Calendar()
res = p.parse('this month')
print(str(res))
```

Returns:

```
(time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=16, tm_min=22, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=194, tm_isdst=0), 0)
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: Posted. Other strings that I've tried that basically return the same thing: "first day of this month", "current month"

Comment: `parsedatetime` seems to support `eom` but not `bom`.  This can be seen in the [code](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime/blob/master/parsedatetime/__init__.py#L887).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used parsedatetime for this though that's an interesting way to get the first of the month.  Still, I generally do this:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

It's less wasteful of resources, too, since you don't have to parse any text at runtime, but that's an aside, really.

You can convert this to a time.struct_time via timetuple():

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0).timetuple()
```

time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=182, tm_isdst=-1)

Comment: Yeah, probably the best way. I'm using it because it's also useful for getting things like the first day of the week without having to do a bunch of calculations.

Comment: Funnily enough, this actually works: "last month +1 month"

Comment: I usually do something like that but directly with datetime (timedelta of +1 month against the datetime produced with the code I referenced).  It makes a lot of sense that this would work in parsedatetime since it's implemented on top of datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been time to this question but I would like to share the trick I found as parsedatetime does not have `bom` nor `bow`
I have used the following sneaky trick to get upper bound for current month and the upper bound for the current week like this
`res = p.parse("one month after last month")` returns the start of the current month
`res = p.parse("one week after last week")` returns the start of the current week